# Problema al cerrar u ocultar formulario en c#

Tags: c#

tengo un programa con dos formularios, en uno tengo un login y cuando inicias sesión debe cerrarse y abrirse el otro, el problema esta cuando quiero cerrar el login que no se cierra.
He probado con `this.close` o `this.hide` pero no hace nada, también he probado en el segundo formulario a poner

```
Login formMain = new Login();
formMain.Show();
```

pero sigue sin hacer nada, el formulario principal no se cierra, alguna idea de por que falla?.

UPDATE - 1

```
Form2 formMain = new Form2();
formMain.Show();
this.Close();
//this.Hide();
```

Comment: ¿Hablas de *winforms*?

Comment: Si, windows form

Comment: Por lo que se, no puedes cerrar el formulario principal (el primer form padre), por que al cerrarlo, el programa terminaría si lo que quieres es cerrar el formulario de login, debes hacer que el form login, sea hijo de un form principal que se mantenga oculto hasta que el form login valide ok y entonces mostrarlo.

Comment: Puedes indicar quien llama a quien?

Comment: @DarkFrostnight el formulario de login llama al hijo (no se si esto a lo que te refieres)

Comment: entonces el form de login es el principal, el que tienes puesto en el main ?

Comment: Si, el principal es el login, si no inicias sesión no puedes acceder al formulario2

Comment: Entonces no puedes cerrarlo, solo puedes ocultarlo y abrir el formulario 2 y cuando cierras el formulario dos muestras nuevamente el login, si me dejas el código mas completo, te dejo una respuesta con ejemplo.

Comment: Lo estoy intentando dejar en oculto pero tampoco me funciona, te dejo un poco más de código pero tampoco hay mucho más código que enseñar

Comment: Te deje una respuesta, si es necesario, la vamos trabajando para hacerla mas completa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es ocultar tu form padre antes de llamar al hijo, si no, hasta que no se cierre el hijo, no se ocultara el padre, es solo cosa de orden, prueba con esto:

```
Hide();
Form2 formMain = new Form2();
formMain.ShowDialog(this);
Show();
```

Comment: Lo acabo de ver en otra web, esto es la mejor solución que he encontrado, muchas gracias,